# Creating Backup and Restore where the Executable path in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, backup, restore

it seems i have some difficulty here some of the questions in google is quite not suited for my problem.

> my backup code:

```
mb.ExportToFile(" '" & Application.ExecutablePath & "'\backup.sql")
```

> my restore code:

```
mb.ImportFromFile(" '" & Application.ExecutablePath & "'\backup.sql")
```

i want that my back up is always where my exe file or near. i think this is posible.

> it says: "The given path's format is not supported."

Comment: the `System.IO.Path` class has some great methods to parse and combine file names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.ExecutablePath` method returns the executable name also ... you need to use this one:

```
mb.ExportToFile(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) & "\backup.sql")
```

Comment: i try now my code looks like this "'" & strPath & "'\backup.sql" and give the same error.

Comment: Take out your single quotes

Comment: thank you for the quick reply i think i am blind for the quotes. this works now mb.ExportToFile(strpath & "\backup.sql")